# How to solve localtime_r timezone segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, beagleboneblack, localtime

I was using **localtime** on my BeagleBone Black to time stamp events. I'm running a multi-threaded application and realized that localtime is not thread safe. So I switched to **localtime_r** and this generates a **segmentation fault**. Please find attached the image.

[image]

- *I executed the same program on my Desktop which is x86_64 system with a different linux kernel version and it works*. Tried it again with another 64 bit system with a more recent kernel and it does not work.
- Did not find much literature online regarding this issue. [This](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1390) has some info but is not clear.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this? Not sure why it works on some systems and not on others.

Update 1: I've posted the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(){

int day, month, hour, minute, second, year;

time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *result;
struct tm *tm = localtime_r(&t, result);

day = result->tm_mday;
month = (result->tm_mon+1);
hour = result->tm_hour;
minute = result->tm_min;
second = result->tm_sec;
year = (result->tm_year-100);


printf("%d : %d : %d : %d:%d:%d\n", month, day, year, hour, minute, second);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you could post your code here.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct tm *result;
struct tm *tm = localtime_r(&t, result);
```

You passed garbage to `localtime_r`. You didn't initialize `result` to anything in particular but passed its value to `localtime_r`.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm result;
struct tm *tm = localtime_r(&t, &result);
```

Comment: should that be localtime_r(&t`m`, &result); ?

Comment: Thanks. I am experiencing a similar problem.  I saw your answer, but didn't notice `time_t t = time(NULL);` in the original question

Comment: I have added that your answer, so we can delete these comments now :-)

Answer (score 3):

Seg fault is occurring as you are trying to access a memory which you do not own.
Use this

```
//struct tm *result ;
struct tm result;
struct tm *tm = localtime_r(&t, &result);
```